# django full text search taggit

Tags: python, django, postgresql, tags, full-text-search

### My application - the basics

I have a simple django application which allows for storing information about certain items and I'm trying to implement a search view/functionality.

I'm using `django-taggit` to tag the items by their functionality/features.

### What I want to implement

I want to implement a full text search which allows to search across all the fields of the items, including their tags.

### The problem(s)

1. On the results view, the tagged items are showing up multiple times (one occurence per tag)
2. The ranking is correct when I specify * only a single* tag in the search field, but when I specify *multiple* tag names, I will get unexpected ranking results.

I suspect the `SearchVector()` does not resolve the tags relation as I expected it to do. The tags should be treated just like a list of words in this case.

### Example Code

#### models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Item(models.Model):
    identifier = models.SlugField('ID', unique=True, editable=False)
    short_text = models.CharField('Short Text', max_length=100, blank=True)
    serial_number = models.CharField('Serial Number', max_length=30, blank=True)
    revision = models.CharField('Revision/Version', max_length=30, blank=True)
    part_number = models.CharField('Part Number', max_length=30, blank=True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField('Manufacturer', max_length=30, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField('Description', blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager('Tags', blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Active', default=True)
```

#### forms.py

```py
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=False)
    active_only = forms.BooleanField(initial=True, label='Show active items only', required=False)
```

#### views.py

```py
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery, SearchVector, SearchRank

from . import models
from . import forms

class ItemListView(ListView):
    form_class = forms.SearchForm
    model = models.Item
    fields = ['serial_number', 'part_number', 'manufacturer', 'tags', 'is_active']
    template_name_suffix = '_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data['active_only']:
                queryset = queryset.filter(is_active=True)

            if not form.cleaned_data['search']:
                return super().get_queryset()

            search_vector = SearchVector('identifier', 'short_text', 'serial_number', 'revision', 'part_number',
                                         'manufacturer', 'description', 'tags')
            search_query = SearchQuery(form.cleaned_data['search'], search_type='websearch')
            return (
                queryset.annotate(
                    search=search_vector, rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
                )
                # .filter(search=search_query)
                .order_by("-rank").distinct()
            ) #.filter(search__icontains=form.cleaned_data['search'],)
        return super().get_queryset()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding the tags field directly to your `SearchVector`

Lets concatenate the tags with Django's `StringAgg` into a single string and then use that string in your `SearchVector`

first we import `StringAgg`

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
```

then this is how you have to change your `get_queryset` function

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data['active_only']:
            queryset = queryset.filter(is_active=True)

        if not form.cleaned_data['search']:
            return queryset

        queryset = queryset.annotate(tags_str=StringAgg('tags__name', delimiter=' '))
        search_vector = SearchVector('identifier', 'short_text', 'serial_number', 'revision', 'part_number',
                                     'manufacturer', 'description', 'tags_str')
        search_query = SearchQuery(form.cleaned_data['search'], search_type='websearch')
        return (
            queryset.annotate(
                search=search_vector, rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query)
            )
            .order_by("-rank").distinct()
        )
    return queryset
```